# problem with linespacing

Tags: parskip

First, I'd like to remove the space above the first line due to `\baselineskip`. This variable can't be given a value lower than the font size. It crashes saying something like "wrong units".

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage[verbose,vmargin=20mm,hmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontsize}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}
\pagestyle{empty}
\changefontsize{24}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[height=70mm]{example-image-10x16}
\hfill
\includegraphics[height=70mm]{example-image-10x16} \\

\begin{center}
    \begin{bfseries}
    {\LARGErrr My title}\\
    \end{bfseries}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here between the bottom of the images and the top of "My title" there's a space due to the font size set by `\changefontsize`. Also if I use `\centering` instead on `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` that space vanishes. If anybody could explain it. If I remove any centering effect (neither use of `\begin{center} ...` nor of `\centering`) then the space is reduced to half.

Comment: dont ignore warnings! `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 15--18` latex is warning you about the misplaced `\\ ` (which should never be at the end of the paragraph) and is forcing the spurious blank line (not a vertical space) that you are asking about.

Comment: Because you are using cm fonts you are not getting font sizes close to your requested size `LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences (Font)              up to 22.82007pt have occurred.`  use `fix-cm` package.

Comment: About `\centering`: As you noticed, this command just center the text  whereas the center environment also add some space before and after the text. There are nothing more to explain. The command and the environment is not one the same hairy beast.